# Chrome external extension not shown in extension list

Tags: google-chrome-extension, registry, setup-project

I'm trying to install a Chrome external extension using a visual studio setup project and following the instructions listed in http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry, I did the following to add an external extension to Google chrome:

1. Packed the extension and moved the resulting .crx file to a folder C:\Hafez\Grid_Bootstrapper
2. I've added a registry sub key named fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea under the following path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions\ with the next two values:

   - **1.path** with a value of "C:\Hafez\Grid_Bootstrapper\fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea.crx" and
   - **2.version** with a value of "1.0.0.1"

   which are, by the way, the exact values but unfortunately when I start Chrome the extension is not listed.

BTW, I'm doing this in a installer custom action and it writes the values exactly the way I want them.

I can't find what is wrong because I do the exact steps listed in the link.
May you discover what have I done wrong?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the extension I'm trying to install was already installed before. Thought that might make any difference to you.